# python panda: return indexes of common rows

Tags: python, pandas

Apologies, if this is a fairly newbie question. I was trying to find which rows  are common between two data frames. The return values should be the row indexes of `df2` that are common with `df1`. My clunky example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['cx','cx','cx2'], 'col2':[1,4,12]})
df1['col2'] = df1['col2'].map(str);
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['cx','cx','cx','cx','cx2','cx2'], 'col2':[1,3,5,10,12,12]})
df2['col2'] = df2['col2'].map(str);

df1['idx'] = df1[['col1','col2']].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x),axis=1);
df2['idx'] = df2[['col1','col2']].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x),axis=1);

df1['idx_values'] = df1.index.values
df2['idx_values'] = df2.index.values

df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,on = 'idx');
myindexes = df3['idx_values_y'];

myindexes.to_csv(idir + 'test.txt',sep='\t',index = False);
```

The return values should be `[0,4,5]`. It would be great to have this done efficiently since the two dataframes would have several million rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New column with join values is not necessary, merge by default inner merge by both columns and if need values of `df2.index` add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['cx','cx','cx2'], 'col2':[1,4,12]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['cx','cx','cx','cx','cx2','cx2'], 'col2':[1,3,5,10,12,12]})

df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2.reset_index(), on = ['col1','col2'])
print (df3)
  col1 col2  index
0   cx    1      0
1  cx2   12      4
2  cx2   12      5
```

For both indexes need:

```
df4 = pd.merge(df1.reset_index(),df2.reset_index(), on = ['col1','col2'])
print (df4)

   index_x col1  col2  index_y
0        0   cx     1        0
1        2  cx2    12        4
2        2  cx2    12        5
```

For only intersection of both DataFrames:

```
df5 = pd.merge(df1,df2, on = ['col1','col2'])
#if 2 column DataFrame   
#df5 = pd.merge(df1,df2)
print (df5)

  col1  col2
0   cx     1
1  cx2    12
2  cx2    12
```

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be done by merging (inner join) both dataframes:

```
common_rows = pd.merge(df1, df2.reset_index(), how='inner', on=['idx_values'])
```